# flutter app is not running by flutter build ios but runs by xcode

Tags: ios, flutter, flutter-ios, flutter-ios-build

I wrote flutter application, I opened ios section by xcode and the application is running , but when I run application by vscode by `flutter build ios`  I got this error:

```
Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified development team in Xcode project: FHDGDHARTT
Running pod install...                                              4.1s
Running Xcode build...                                          
Xcode build done.                                            4.1s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    2021-08-27 15:20:15.391 XCBBuildService[25359:181696] Failed to remove: /Users/alt/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-cwssrvwaltuodobbealdvrytptog/Build/Intermediates.noindex/XCBuildData/7c6f3b0142d0b109056c8c9053a39860-manifest.xcbuild: unlink(/Users/alt/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-cwssrvwaltuodobbealdvrytptog/Build/Intermediates.noindex/XCBuildData/7c6f3b0142d0b109056c8c9053a39860-manifest.xcbuild): No such file or directory (2)
    2021-08-27 15:20:15.617 XCBBuildService[25359:181696] Failed to remove: /Users/alt/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-cwssrvwaltuodobbealdvrytptog/Build/Intermediates.noindex/XCBuildData/7c6f3b0142d0b109056c8c9053a39860-desc.xcbuild: unlink(/Users/alt/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-cwssrvwaltuodobbealdvrytptog/Build/Intermediates.noindex/XCBuildData/7c6f3b0142d0b109056c8c9053a39860-desc.xcbuild): No such file or directory (2)
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Analyzing workspace
    note: Constructing build description
    note: Build preparation complete
    /Users/alt/Mobile/Projects/shave-machine-app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'FMDB' from project 'Pods')
    error: No profiles for 'com.shavemachine.shaveMachineApp' were found: Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'com.shavemachine.shaveMachineApp'. Automatic signing is disabled and unable to generate a profile. To enable automatic signing, pass -allowProvisioningUpdates to xcodebuild. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    /Users/alt/Mobile/Projects/shave-machine-app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'Reachability' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/alt/Mobile/Projects/shave-machine-app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'Flutter' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/alt/Mobile/Projects/shave-machine-app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'TOCropViewController-TOCropViewControllerBundle' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/alt/Mobile/Projects/shave-machine-app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'TOCropViewController' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/alt/Mobile/Projects/shave-machine-app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'Toast' from project 'Pods')

Encountered error while building for device.
alt@alts-MacBook-Pro shave-machine-app % ff clean    
Cleaning Xcode workspace...                                      2,742ms
Deleting build...                                                   50ms
Deleting .dart_tool...                                               2ms
Deleting .packages...                                                0ms
Deleting Generated.xcconfig...                                       0ms
Deleting flutter_export_environment.sh...                            0ms
Deleting Flutter.podspec...                                          0ms
Deleting .flutter-plugins-dependencies...                            0ms
Deleting .flutter-plugins...                                         0ms
alt@alts-MacBook-Pro shave-machine-app % ff pub get
Running "flutter pub get" in shave-machine-app...                 1,147ms
alt@alts-MacBook-Pro shave-machine-app % ff build ios
Building com.shavemachine.shaveMachineApp for device (ios-release)...
Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified development team in Xcode project: FHDGDHARTT
Running pod install...                                              5.5s
Running Xcode build...                                          
Xcode build done.                                            4.4s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Analyzing workspace
    note: Constructing build description
    note: Build preparation complete
    /Users/alt/Mobile/Projects/shave-machine-app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'FMDB' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/alt/Mobile/Projects/shave-machine-app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'TOCropViewController' from project 'Pods')
    error: No profiles for 'com.shavemachine.shaveMachineApp' were found: Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'com.shavemachine.shaveMachineApp'. Automatic signing is disabled and unable to generate a profile. To enable automatic signing, pass -allowProvisioningUpdates to xcodebuild. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    /Users/alt/Mobile/Projects/shave-machine-app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'Reachability' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/alt/Mobile/Projects/shave-machine-app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'Flutter' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/alt/Mobile/Projects/shave-machine-app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'TOCropViewController-TOCropViewControllerBundle' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/alt/Mobile/Projects/shave-machine-app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'Toast' from project 'Pods')

Encountered error while building for device.
```

.this is doctor :

```
✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.3, on macOS 11.5.2 20G95 darwin-x64, locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 2.2.3 at /Users/alt/fvm/versions/stable
    • Framework revision f4abaa0735 (8 weeks ago), 2021-07-01 12:46:11 -0700
    • Engine revision 241c87ad80
    • Dart version 2.13.4

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/alt/Mobile/Sdk/Andriod/
    • Platform android-31, build-tools 31.0.0
    • ANDROID_HOME = /Users/alt/Mobile/Sdk/Andriod
    • Java binary at: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_301.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_301-b09)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 12.5.1, Build version 12E507
    • CocoaPods version 1.11.0.rc.1

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[!] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    ✗ Unable to find bundled Java version.
    • Try updating or re-installing Android Studio.

[✓] VS Code (version 1.59.1)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.25.0

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • iPod touch (7th generation) (mobile) • 9318977C-48B1-4E5E-A483-460F582C9794 • ios            • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-14-5 (simulator)
    • Chrome (web)                         • chrome                               • web-javascript • Google Chrome 92.0.4515.159

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, it's a cocoa pods issue, I have to update my cocoa pods and it's working fine for me

you can use these commands using

```
brew install cocoapods
```

if still have issues then you have to install Xcode developer tools using these commands

```
xcode-select --install
```

Answer (score -2):

First step:

[image]

second step:

> flutter clean

Then,

> pod install

after that

> flutter build ios

hope this will resolve your issue, Happy fluttering :)

Comment: when I run pod install I got this https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/5bNFgKkKQm/

Comment: When I run flutter run ios I got this error after running up command https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/fn9qTtR3rC/. I am trying run application on simulator as debug mode

Comment: okay then, Tyr this command => flutter build ios --release --no-tree-shake-icons

Comment: if this also not working for you then you can generate your build from XCode.I'll let you know the steps afterwards if you don't know how to generate okay, But first, run the above and get the result for it.