# Getting error while run flutter app in iOS

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-ios

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 12 Pro Max in debug mode...
```

Running pod install...
CocoaPods' output:
↳
CDN: trunk Relative path: CocoaPods-version.yml exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update

Error output from CocoaPods:
↳
WARNING: CocoaPods requires your terminal to be using UTF-8 encoding.
Consider adding the following to ~/.profile:

```
    export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
    
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/unicode_normalize/normalize.rb:141:in `normalize': Unicode Normalization not appropriate for ASCII-8BIT (Encoding::CompatibilityError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:166:in `unicode_normalize'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:166:in `installation_root'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:226:in `podfile_path'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:105:in `markdown_podfile'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:30:in `report'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:66:in `report_error'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:396:in `handle_exception'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:337:in `rescue in run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:324:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/unicode_normalize/normalize.rb:141:in `normalize': Unicode Normalization not appropriate for ASCII-8BIT (Encoding::CompatibilityError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:166:in `unicode_normalize'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:166:in `installation_root'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:226:in `podfile_path'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:205:in `podfile'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:160:in `verify_podfile_exists!'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:46:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone 12 Pro Max.

[image]

[image]

Comment: you can check my answer for resolve yours => https://stackoverflow.com/a/68953521/16252358

Comment: Thanks @TusharPatel sir, but I'm getting same error on pod install?

Comment: hey did you find the solution i am also facing same error

Comment: This worked for me:
flutter clean,
delete /iOS/Pods,
delete /iOS/Podfile.lock,
flutter build ios.

Answer (score 16):

It seems that is a sort of bug/incombatibility issue in Cocoapods v 1.11.0

To fix the issue, I followed these steps and it worked like a charm: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69076515/16881741

Briefly, follow these steps:

1. In your terminal, in ios folder type

   `gem list --local | grep cocoapods`
2. Take note of what is the output of the previous command. It looks like that (please ignore the version near the various entry, this is my output and I already use the version 1.10.1):

`cocoapods (1.10.1)
cocoapods-core (1.10.1)
cocoapods-deintegrate (1.0.5)
cocoapods-downloader (1.5.1)
cocoapods-plugins (1.0.0)
cocoapods-search (1.0.1)
cocoapods-trunk (1.6.0)
cocoapods-try (1.2.0)`

3. One by one, launch the command
   `sudo gem uninstall X`
   substituting the "X" with the name of the cocoapods component, without the version.
   At the end you should obtain this:

`sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods-core
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods-deintegrate
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods-downloader
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods-plugins
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods-search
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods-trunk
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods-try`

Be sure to have included all the component listed in the point n.1 to avoid dirty status

4. Use the command
   `sudo gem install cocoapods -v 1.10.1`
   To obtain the correct version.

All kudos to Esteban Lopez, the author of the answer I linked at the top.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thank you for helping,  I'm already using version 1.11.0,
CocoaPods : 1.11.0
            Ruby : ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [universal.x86_64-darwin20]
        RubyGems : 3.0.3
            Host : macOS 11.5.2 (20G95)
           Xcode : 12.5.1 (12E507)
             Git : git version 2.23.0
    Ruby lib dir : /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib
    Repositories : trunk - CDN - https://cdn.cocoapods.org/

Comment: Please downgrade from 1.11.0 and use version 1.10.1

Comment: Thank you so much, this answer worked for me

Comment: Working like charm. Thanks. please update answer with 'sudo gem install cocoapods -v 1.10.2'

Answer (score 16):

> This issues appeared in Cocoapods 1.11.0 and as many already noticed rolling back to 1.10.2 fixes the issue. But the original issue comes from wrong locale set in the terminal. It has to be a UTF-8-based locale.

The second answer in [here](https://www.py4u.net/discuss/1936582) solved the issue for me.

As stated, just run

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

in your terminal, and the error should go away. Consider adding this to your `.zshrc` file so that it happens automatically in every session.

Comment: This one solved my problem

Answer (score 2):

open terminal
`export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8`
this will solve your issue.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Try `pod install` with default `terminal`.

Comment: This was exactly what worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
flutter clean,
delete /iOS/Pods,
delete /iOS/Podfile.lock,
flutter build ios.
```

my Mac version info:

```
   CocoaPods : 1.11.0
        Ruby : ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [universal.x86_64-darwin20]
    RubyGems : 3.0.3
        Host : macOS 11.5.2 (20G95)
       Xcode : 12.5.1 (12E507)
         Git : git version 2.23.0
Ruby lib dir : /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib
Repositories : trunk - CDN - https://cdn.cocoapods.org/
```

Comment: NOTE: In all M1 machines, Android Studio & IntelliJ Idea terminal does not compile the pod install command yet. but all other terminals do it. I don't know the why.

This is my observation.

Answer (score 0):

Ran the same project on VCode and it worked successfully, guess the issue was with my Android Studio.

Comment: In all M1 machines, Android Studio & IntelliJ Idea terminal does not compile the pod install command yet. but all other terminals do it. I don't know the why.

This is my observation.

Answer (score -1):

Upgrade Ruby is another way to resolve this issue.